# Retornar maior valor de um registro especifico SQL

Tags: sql, data

Preciso que meu SQL retorne a maior data, mas não a maior data entre todos os registros, e sim, a maior data de um id especifico.

Já tentei utilizar o `MAX()`, mas ele retorna o maior valor de todos da table, bem como um `ORDER BY` para ordenar do maior para o menor e um LIMIT para pegar só o maior.

A pesquisa resumida é a seguinte:

```
    SELECT cob.id, animais.nome, cob.data
    FROM animais
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, id_animal, data FROM animais_movimento WHERE 
    id_tipo_movimento = 1) AS cob ON animais.id = cob.id_animal
```

Dela, gostaria que somente retornasse o valor com a data maior. Dessa forma, retorna duas linhas como resultado, resolveria utilizar um LIMIT ou ORDER BY no final, porém, no SQL completo tem mais JOINS com outras subquerys, enfim.

O banco resumidamente fica assim:

**animais:**

```
ID  |  NOME 
20  |  Teste
```

**animais_movimento:**

```
ID | ID_ANIMAL | DATA
1  | 20        | 01/07/2016
2  | 20        | 10/07/2016
```

Comment: e você quer que retorne essa ultima linha?

Comment: Sim, nesse exemplo, quero que retorne somente o registro com ID 2, que é o que tem a maior data.

Comment: Veja se a resposta legal atende

Comment: Valeu, ajudou bastante, mas não completamente, com isso consegui montar o SQL, mas não está 100% ainda, vou postar mais detalhes como resposta.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, está retornando certo precisei só dar uma adaptada para implementar no SQL completo, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [group by](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) para agrupa os dados iguais e o [max](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql) para pegar a ultima data.

```
SELECT max (cob.id), animais.nome, max(cob.data)
FROM animais
 JOIN animais_movimento cob 
ON animais.id = cob.id_animal
group by animais.nome
```